# Folium: Add PopUp to Polygon Shapes in Choropleth

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

In [the example](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/Popups.ipynb), it shows you can do:

```
m = folium.Map([45, 0], zoom_start=4)
gj = folium.GeoJson(
    data={
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[[27, 43], [33, 43], [33, 47], [27, 47]]]
    }
)
gj.add_child(folium.Popup('outline Popup on GeoJSON'))
gj.add_to(m)
m
```

to add a popup to a single shape, but I have many shapes I made a choropleth with, and I want each to be clickable with a popup saying its properties. I'm working in a jupyter notebook, so I would really like something that can function there instead of doing something with the output in Leaflet.js.

Comment: I believe this feature is in the works https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/376 .  That link contains some workarounds.